# How I Can change value last working date input text without using submit button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I work on asp.net MVC . I need to update last working date

based on request no when value Last working date changed .

I need to using ajax jQuery to do that

Web API I will call it using jQuery ajax is `Resignation/Edit`

Resignation is controller and Edit is action and I will pass

object to Edit action result include request no and last working date .

my code as below :

```
public class ResignationRequester
{


    [Display(Name = "Request No")]
    public int RequestNo { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Working Day: ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime LastWorkingDate { get; set; }
}



[HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ResignationRequester req)
  {
//UPDATE last working date based on Request No
  }



@model HR.WorkforceRequisition.Models.ResignationRequester

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutResignation.cshtml";
}








    <table style="border: 1px solid black;width:100%;">

        <tr>
            <td class="hover" style="width: 50%; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
                <div class="form-group hover">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                    <div class="col-md-7" id="RequestNo">
                        @Model.RequestNo
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>




       
         <tr>
     
     <td class="hover" style="width: 50%; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
         <div class="form-group hover">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastWorkingDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
             <div class="col-md-7">
               
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastWorkingDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
             </div>
         </div>
     </td>
 </tr>

       



    </table>



    

</div>
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. Something like a listener/observer that auto updates the front end when there is a change for the "Last Working Date" in the DB?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What's your goal and what's the problem you're facing?